# How to shorten URLs of static website copy to have less than 256 characters? (created with wget)

Tags: linux, windows, bash, wget

I have to create a full website copy / mirror of https://www.landesmuseum-mecklenburg.de. This copy has to run locally on a Windows 7 system, which has no network connection. Windows 7 has a path length limitation (255), which is reached in my case. How do I circumvent this?

I create a static website copy on a Debian system with: `wget --mirror --adjust-extension --convert-links --restrict-file-names=windows --page-requisites -e robots=off --no-clobber --no-parent --base=./ https://www.landesmuseum-mecklenburg.de/`.

This way I got nearly everything I need. Some special URLs / images are downloaded via a seperated URL-list via: `wget -c -x -i imagelist.txt`

After I create an archive out of this files and transfer them to my Windows 7 Test system and extract them to a local Webserver (called "MiniWebserver") I can visit http://localhost/ and everything seems to work.

But some deep links, especially images have a path length in the windows NTFS filesystem of over 255 characters. All these images are not displayed in the local webpage.

I tried the `-nH --cut-dirs=5` option of wget, but with no acceptable result (the index.html gets overwritten each time).

Another idea was to use the DOS path shorten compatbility feature, so that long directory names would be translated to 8 character names. E.g. `longdirname` translated to `longdi~1`. But I have no idea how to automate this.

**Update: Yet another idea**

One more thing, which came to my mind was to use hashes over the entire path (e.g. md5) and use this instead of the full path + filename. Additionally all URLs in the downloaded .html files must be substituted processed too. But again: I have no idea how to accomplish this using Debian command line tools.

Comment: Ditching Windows seems like the obvious win-win solution. Maybe run the web server in Virtualbox or similar if you are not yet ready to get rid of Windows entirely.

Comment: I would, if I could so easily. But the target system is an embedded one. (
Samsung SUR40 Surface Tablet; A large Table-Tablet). The specs are quite low, and I don't know, if a Virtualbox VM would run on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
wget --trust-server-names <url>
```

> --trust-server-names
>
> If this is set to on, on a redirect the last component of the
>   redirection URL will be used as the local file name. By default it is
>   used the last component in the original URL.

Comment: Hello,
this doesn't seem to work. Even with this option activated, the index.html page gets overwritten. (If `-nH --cut-dirs=5` options are used)